# Matplotlib not installing in PyCharm with no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip, pycharm

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KcL0.png)

I'm setting up my virtual environment and need the Matplotlib library. But when i try installing it using pip install matplotlib(or through the PyCharm IDE or by downloading the latest matplotlib.whl file) it says 'processing matplotlib.....' and exits the installation. I have been struggling with it since few months. And even tried with different laptops. Same problem.

PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.7479.30, built on May 29, 2019
Windows 10 10.0

Python 3.7

Thanks.

Comment: try `python -m pip install matplotlib`, can you show a traceback, I understand that you're not getting any errors but can you try and paste what you're doing on your terminal?

Comment: C:\Users\uddipaan.hazarika>python -m pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/c0/69e3f695d7384012e90be1e16570c08953baae00fd98094179ef87c7d5a2/matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

C:\Users\uddipaan.hazarika>

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this path for installing matplotlib or other lib on PyCharm, first go to this path `file->settings->project interpreter-> find matplotlib` and choose project interpreter and installed package successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps:

1. Restore to default settings (optional)

   To restore the PyCharm default settings, you can remove the configuration directory idea.config.path when the IDE is not running. The directory is located in:
   `SYSTEM DRIVE\Users\USER ACCOUNT NAME\.PRODUCT VERSION`
2. Then run this command in command prompt

   ```
   C:\Windows\System32>pip install matplotlib
   ```

   (considering default directory)
   I think this will install matplotlib SUCCESSFULLY!